# How do I prevent Vetur and TypeScript from both showing typescript warnings in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

I'm working on a Vue2 project that uses TypeScript. I'm using VSCode with the Vetur and TypeScript extensions installed.

Whenever a TypeScript warning occurs, the VSCode overlay shows the identical warning being reported by both TypeScript and Vetur.

[image: warnings]

Additionally, any intellisense menus show the options twice.

[image: intellisense]

I'd like to keep both extensions installed. How can I get them to play nice with each other and only display the warnings once?

Comment: It is just a guess but it may be because both extensions are using different versions of TS. Vetur has a [setting](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/FAQ.html#vetur-uses-different-version-of-typescript-in-vue-files-to-what-i-installed-in-node-modules) to use the workspace version of TS (simply from `node_modules`] and I bet TS extension for VS will have something similar. Also note that Vetur is no longer officially recommended tool to use with Vue+TS but [Volar is](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#editor-support) - from my personal experience, it is really better

Comment: @MichalLevý I have Volar installed as well for my Vue 3 projects, but I need Vetur for my older Vue 2 projects.

Comment: @MichalLevý I enabled `use workspace dependencies` and restarted the Vetur vue language service (VLS) but sadly, it's still doubling up the highlighting.

Comment: @MichalLevý On a whim I disabled Vuter and Volar seems to have picked up the slack even on my Vue 2 projects. If you want to write a formal answer, I'd happily give you the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be because both extensions are using different versions of TS. Vetur has a [setting](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/FAQ.html#vetur-uses-different-version-of-typescript-in-vue-files-to-what-i-installed-in-node-modules) to use the workspace version of TS (simply from `node_modules`) and I bet TS extension for VS will have something similar.

Also note that Vetur is no longer officially recommended tool to use with Vue+TS but [Volar](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#editor-support) is - from my personal experience, it is really better and more actively develop (even have support for `script setup` with no perfect but pretty decent auto-conversion between Options API/Composition API and `script setup`)

While Volar says it is designed for Vue 3, it still works fine with Vue 2 and the composition API. So it should be safe to disable Vetur in VSCode if you have Volar enabled.